# jquery slideshow need images to seamlessly fade from one to the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have a jquery slide show that right now fades from image to image. Ideally I would like the next image to appear by the time the previous slide is finished.

Here is the script that is calling the fade any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
slidesContainer
    .find(options.slides)
    .filter(':visible')
    .hide()
    .end()
    .end()
    .find(options.slides)
    .filter(':eq('+ordernum+')')
    .stop()
    .fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(2000);
```

Comment: Can you add all the other relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hiding the current visible slide before you have any slides behind it and then waiting for the next one to fade in. I would first make sure I have a visible slide behind and then fade the top, but you could create a queue and fade both at the same time (fade one in while fading the one out).

Answer (score 0):

look at [this](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow) page

```
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
```